# How to check an element is having display block / none style in Protractor?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor, e2e-testing, angular-e2e

I'm having two div's which are having same css, only difference is the style is having display:block and none.

```
<div class="autocomplete-suggestions " style="left: 91px; top: 333px; min-width: 747px; display: none;">
   <div>item1</div>
<div>item2</div>
</div>

<div class="autocomplete-suggestions " style="left: 91px; top: 333px; min-width: 747px; display: block;">
   <div>item3</div>
<div>item4</div>
</div>
```

How we could identify the which element is having the style display block or none in Protractor?

I need to click item3 div which is reside with display:block div.

I have tried the below code.

```
browser.findElements(by.css('.autocomplete-suggestions')).then((autoSuggestions) => {
            autoSuggestions.map((item) => {
                if (item.isDisplayed()) {
                    item.getTagName().then((x) => {
                        console.log('tagname', x);
                    });
                    browser.pause();
                    //item[index].click();
                }
            })
```

from the above code i can see both div's.

I'm receiving 'could not find element 'click on undefined' error.

I'm trying end to end testing with Anuglar 7, protractor, jasmine and selenium web driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter your expression to take into consideration the [`style` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_style.asp).

You might find [XPath selector](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) easier to write/read/understand, you can use [XPath `contains()` function](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=55281024)  to select only `div` which has `display: block` in the `style` attribute  would be:

```
//div[contains(@class,'autocomplete-suggestions') and contains(@style, 'display: block')]/div[1]
```

Demo:

[image]

---

If you would like to stay with [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp) the equivalent expression will be:

```
div[class*="autocomplete-suggestions"][style *= "display: block"] >:nth-child(1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I'll try your code and 'll update you.

Comment: I've tried with your code.. working fine.. Thank you @Dmitri

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an option using CSS as locator then you can use this

`element(by.cssContainingText(".autocomplete-suggestions[style*='display: block'] div", "item3"))`